# Sending automated emails using Gmail API with Java and Oauth authentication

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have a web app which sends emails (gmail) in name of my users

When a user registers, she supplies gmail account and password. Also she has to enable access for Less Secure Apps (I recommend to create a new account for this)

Then I can open a gmail session

```
session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
    }
});
```

and send emails on her behalf.

Unfortunately this is going to stop working next 30th May, when Google will allow only OAUTH2 access

I have followed [Java Quickstart for Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) and I have code up and running for sending emails with OAUTH2: enable gmail api, create an application on google cloud platform, grant send permission, oauth2 client id credential created...

The problem I have is I can't see a way to automatize this task because when creating an authorized credential, a consent screen displays on browser and you have to select the account to be granted manually (maybe because my app in google cloud platform is still pending to be reviewed)

Is there a way to infer the gmail account you want to access from the credentials file (client_secret.json)? Is there a way to automatize this?

Answer (score 2):

No, or yes. It depends.

The whole point of OAuth2 is to improve security by working with authorization tokens rather than asking for user credentials. To do this the user has to *consent* to the app's access request, and thus the OAuth consent screen **cannot** be bypassed. This is
[explained](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/auth-overview) in Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent). It's not related to your app's review status but rather it's the way OAuth works.

You can still work in a similar way, though . Instead of asking for username and password upon the user's registration you can redirect them to the OAuth consent screen so they can authorize your app. Make sure that your app is requesting [offline](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline) access type and then you can retrieve an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. These will essentially work as your credentials and you can use the refresh token to generate new access tokens when needed without having the user go through the consent screen each time.

The refresh token doesn't have a "natural" expiration so you can keep using it indefinitely, but there are a few scenarios where it will become [invalid](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration), such as it not being used for six months, the user changing passwords (if using Gmail scopes), the user manually revoking access, etc. In these cases you will need to direct them to the consent screen again to reauthorize your app.

In this sense, your app can still work automatically without user input except the initial setup, which you already had to deal with when they supplied you with their credentials. The refresh token expiration can even be compared to what you had to do when the users changed their passwords in your current workflow.

One exception to this are [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount). If you and your users are part of a Google Workspace domain you can [delegate](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) domain-wide access to it, then the service account will be able to access user data without any manual input. Of course, this is because as the domain administrator you pretty much own all the accounts under it. But if you're working with a publicly available application you will have to deal with the limitations I mentioned above.

### Sources:

- [Google's auth overview](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/auth-overview)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)
- [OAuth 2.0 for web applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)
- [The OAuth consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent)

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes after a litle bit more of documentation I have arrived to your same conclusion. Thank you